# In Ruby, how do you reverse dns lookup the hostname of a zeroconf/bonjour computer?

Tags: ruby, mdns

Neither

```
Resolv.getname( "fred.local" ) 
Resolv.getaddress( "10.0.1.18" )
```

nor

```
Socket.gethostbyaddr([10,0,1,18].pack("CCCC"))
```

seem to recognize hosts on the local subnet which use zeroconf/bonjour.  I need to find the hostname of a zeroconf computer on the local subnet given its ip address.

Comment: Perhaps something like this: `h_n = Socket.getaddrinfo('10.0.1.18', nil)`  might work. The hostname should be located at: `h_n[0][2]`

Comment: Just returns '10.0.1.18' as the hostname...[["AF_INET", 0, "10.0.1.18", "10.0.1.18", 2, 2, 17], ["AF_INET", 0, "10.0.1.18", "10.0.1.18", 2, 1, 6]]

Answer (score 1):

Those function speak regular TCP and DNS, I would assume you need to use a bonjour API, such as http://dnssd.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Didn't figure out how to get dnssd to do the name lookup.  Tried the net-mdns gem, using Resolv::MDNS.getname( '10.0.1.18' ), which seems like it should work, returns that it can't find a name for the address.  BTW, I can ping the ip address, and the local name 'fred.local'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the link from DGM's post stopped working and I don't have the rep for comments :)

https://github.com/tenderlove/dnssd